# To what extent should figure legends within scientific literature describe trends in their figures?

Tags: scientific-language

How far should figure legends go in describing the trends within the figure (within a biology paper)?

I've seen some conflicting information on this and I'm unsure if legends need to fully describe trends in the figure, only give a partial description, or leave the reader to observe the trend themselves.

In the main body of the text that the figure will be placed and referenced in, the trend will be described.

Comment: This depends on which discipline of science you are in. Figures in biology papers tend to have much more detailed captions than figures in mathematics papers.

Comment: Sorry, I should have specified! It is for a biology paper - I'll update the post now.

Comment: As far as *should*, is space limited in your article? (In this case, you should put as much description in the caption as you can because the font size is smaller in captions.) Can the reader understand the figure just from the caption without finding the appropriate description in the text? (This is the ideal in biology, and I think it's a good idea for all fields, although in many of them, like mathematics, it's not actually practiced.)

Comment: Thank you for the insight, in the end I decided to keep all information necessary for the understanding of the figure without the main text to support it but I stripped off the description of the figure's trends.

Comment: This question is off-topic in only allowing opinions as answers, presuming that the instruction to authors of the journal to which you are submitting does not contain explicit instructions. But why ask strangers? If you are a biologist and read papers, you have only to ask yourself what style makes for a paper that it easy to follow. Others may agree or disagree with you, but you should do what seems right to you, until any deficiencies are explained to you. Writing in a particular way just because you think it is “scientific style” is a pathetic attitude.

Comment: Those who are voting (as I rather expected) for closure are perhaps missing the point that this is not entirely about opinion but is about the efficient use of space, clarity of expression, the avoidance of repetition, and the usage of English within given constraints. Surely these are themes common to many other questions on this site? We extend the courtesy of answering to others who ask similar but less scientifically-based questions of us.

Comment: I am not a biologist @David, I am sorry that you got that impression. I am a student studying biology and I'm only writing a paper for my university to mark.  I wasn't sure if there was a standard regarding my question in scientific literature, and as I said in the main body of the question, I have received conflicting information on the topic.

Comment: @David: "If you are a biologist and read papers, you have only to ask yourself what style makes for a paper that is easy to follow." No, it doesn't work that way. Biology papers are a genre of writing, and as such, they follow certain rules peculiar to the genre.

Comment: @PeterShor — The context of scientific papers was implied. I was suggesting the poster compared papers he had read. As it turns out he is a student, then the situation is different. However it is still opinion. I used to issue students with advice (with examples) on writing project reports, but that was only my opinion. I did make the rationale clear, which was “tell them a story”. In relation to figures, this meant they should refer to them explicitly in the text as part of the argument — many tended to dump them at the end leaving the reader to work out their relevance.

Comment: @David: "What style makes a paper that is easy to follow" and "how should I write my paper so that it resembles other papers in the same field" are two different questions that may have two different answers. For example, for many years, using the passive voice to avoid the pronouns "I" and "we" was a standard in scientific writing. Adhering to this standard definitely tends to makes papers harder to read.

Comment: @PeterShor — OK. However it's not really a question about the English language if it's about journal style. (I was looking for my own style guide so I could make it available to the poster, but I can't find an electronic copy, and the physical copy is in my office in the Uni which I have only been into once in the last 6 months.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take this as a question about English usage within the constraints of scientific convention. Like some other questions on this site it relates to concise usage, lack of repetition, and clarity of expression. What follows is therefore good practice relating to most figures (but not all) and is not merely a matter of opinion.

Figures are usually shown to present or summarize those data or concepts that are described in the article's prose. They may illustrate examples of things alluded to in the prose. A caption should not duplicate the prose at any length or unnecessarily; this would waste space and would irritate some readers by diversionary repetition of ideas that are already systematically developed in the prose.

The caption should be sufficient to give immediate and concise (even if incomplete) understanding of the core significance of the figure. It should provide a succinct conceptual link between figure and prose by drawing attention to the main theme it illustrates that is developed in more detail within the prose.

Similarly the caption should not repeat unnecessarily any information that is given within the figure (such as the names of the variables already shown on the axes of a simple graph, an embedded title, or the embedded legends).